# How can i fix my low CPU usage?

Tags: windows-8, cpu-usage, fps

I have a very expensive pretty new computer, (Asus rampage III Extreme) (Intel i7 980x) and 2 (nvidia gforce 580 SLI).

So it is a good computer, but when I play games like Borderlands 2 I get much lower FPS than I am suppose to have, like around 30 FPS. And about 150 FPS when I am looking at the ground. The lowest FPS is when I look into like cities and that kind of stuff.

I checked my CPU and GPU usage and noticed that they both only used about 20-40% of their maximum usage. So I think that something is wrong with the CPU.

I have tried reinstalling windows, overclocking and some other BIOS settings. Not funny to pay a lot for a new computer and not be able to play even the games I could play on my last computer.

Comment: Have you adjusted any of the games' settings so rendering is not as intensive on the GPU? The CPU doesn't handle image rendering so it would be normal for low CPU usage.

Comment: Maybe you can get better recommendations at [gaming.se]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not into gaming, but you may want to look at Windows 8 Game Optimization.

E.g. [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/10090/discussions/0/846955554661838222/), [here](http://www.ztuts.com/2013/03/8-ways-to-optimize-windows-8-for-gaming-online-no-lag.html), [here](http://www.registryrecycler.com/blog/2013/02/how-to-optimize-windows-8-to-run-faster/).. There are several settings in Windows 8 that can be tuned (e.g. memory and performance), and above all, services and apps (Metro) that can be disabled. Also, if you've a fresh install of Windows 8, a run of CCleaner or something like that is advisable to get a more shipshape registry, and a disk defragmentation might also be in order.

Also verify you *are* using the latest video drivers and that they're set to a gaming mode (instead of "low RAM impact", "low power", or such). NVidia site offers several tips about that.

Even so, some say that Windows 8's greater bulk (in OS terms) makes for a [poor gaming performance](http://kotaku.com/5936535/windows-8-is-not-good-for-gamers), and some experienced gamers suggest installing a double-booted Windows XP to run games on a leaner platform.

That said, you are aware that the human eye is *unable* to perceive frame rates above about 25 fps (30-35 fps for very young, rested and carrot-fed people)? That's how you can watch TV and see motion instead of 25 still frames each second (never mind that modern TVs all have higher frame rates). I find it difficult to swallow that 30 fps is "unusable". But then, I repeat, I'm no gamer...

Answer (score -2):

Go to Task manager, right click the Process manager/Detail tab, right click the process and set Priority to `Real time`.

I had same problem with games only using about 50% GPU com to find out it was because CPU utilization was low and bottlenecking GPUs.